# How do PrePost annotations stack with HttpSecurity configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm pretty new to Spring Security, and I'm trying to understand the utility of `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize`. These annotations take built-in expressions that can all be put in `HttpSecurity` when configuring `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Trying it with the following Spring Java (Groovy) configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
}
```

And a controller method defined as:

```
@RequestMapping('/data/{id}')
@PreAuthorize('permitAll')
Data getData(@PathParam('id') String id) {
    //return some data
}
```

There seems to be no effect to the controller method. I've been reading the official Spring docs but there doesn't seem to be a more elaborate discussion about this.

Answer (score 0):

These annotations are enabled by EnableGlobalMethodSecurity config annotation of changes to script-security.xml (which you're trying to avoid)

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 ...
}
```